# Vue error when creating a project from Vue CLI

Tags: vue.js

After I create a Vue3 project with the Vue cli tool, my terminal crashes and gives the following error:

```
  Starting GUI...
  Ready on http://localhost:8000
node:events:368
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/xxxx/Desktop/personal/vuetest/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/locales'
    at Object.readdirSync (node:fs:1390:3)
    at exports.readdir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/sync/fs.js:18:20)
    at Object.safeCall [as safe] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/call.js:24:8)
    at DirectoryReader.readNextDirectory (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/directory-reader.js:78:10)
    at Readable.DirectoryReader.stream._read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/directory-reader.js:57:18)
    at Readable.read (node:internal/streams/readable:496:27)
    at readdirSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/sync/index.js:27:21)
    at Function.readdirSyncStat (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/index.js:34:10)
    at ReaderSync.dynamicApi (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fast-glob/out/providers/reader-sync.js:64:24)
    at ReaderSync.api (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fast-glob/out/providers/reader-sync.js:56:25)
Emitted 'error' event on Readable instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'scandir',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/Users/xxxx/Desktop/personal/vuetest/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/locales'
}

Node.js v17.0.1
```

I cannot start the cli again until I delete the project folder. What is the problem here ?

Comment: what command are using to create the project?

Comment: I did it from the vue GUI. Just clicks
But now I did it with `vue create projectName`,
And chose Vue 3 as the options. The project works, but I cannot run `vue ui` because it still fails with that error

Comment: Also try to use LTS version of  nodejs, currently is  `v16.13.1`

Comment: @Radeanu Thank u ! This worked. I recently upgraded my node version, but downgrading it works